# Calculate pc power as server

Tags: web-hosting

Is it possible to calculate the number of visitors I can handle using my PC as a web server?  Does this depend on the website?

Comment: I suggest you just go for a hoster, this will save you you **a lot** time, effort and hassle. Apart from that, there are script you can run to mimic number of visitors, just google for `server load tests`

Comment: I would recommend looking into the free tier for [Amazon Web Services (AWS)](http://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=AWS_Free_Tier_2013).  It would make it easier to scale in the future if you start with it... and it's free for a small site for the first year.  You could also look at the Google cloud platform, though you will incur charges right away with Google (unless you only use the app engine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a very very very(!) rough approximation based on your PC's performance, complexity of the website and your network infrastructure. However, there are lots of issues you need to consider:

- What's the hardware configuration?
- What operating system are you using for this?
- What's your web & database stack?
- What other devices are between you and your ISP? Routers, switches, other machines that share your network load...
- Will you also need to run DNS & email services?
- Will you also run other desktop applications taking up (much of the) resources on your PC?
- Is your website properly developed and optimized?
- Do you have any expectations on the number of visits, peak times & other metrics that would give you an idea of the overall performance?

After you have your domain and server up & running, the best thing you can do is to benchmark your service, using [Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) or various other similar tools to give you some ballpark figures regarding the number of concurrent calls and the overall load that your server is likely to be able to handle.

Comment: You can also use a tool like [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) to perform load testing.